# Sendgrid mailing list id

Tags: php, json, api, curl, sendgrid

Is there any way to get my created mailing list ID in sendgrid without login graphically! knowing that to upload receipients into my list will require its ID as parameter of link..

POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/{list_id}/recipients HTTP/1.1

as mentionned in their website : https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Multiple-Recipients-to-a-List-POST

Answer (score 8):

Really late now, but for anyone looking for solution from SendGrid webapp, you can grab it from the url when you are viewing the list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve your list IDs with a `GET` call to `/lists`

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#List-All-Lists-GET

Comment: Is that means there is no way to get the ID of the list directly by its name for example? As I wanted to add recipients emails to my created list using php without logging in graphically ! so I'm supposed to add the ID to the post link, is there any other possiblity without listing the lists details ?

Comment: Create the list using the POST method and the response will include the new ID. https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Create-a-List-POST

Comment: Yes that is it ! I've decode the json of the response !
One more question, is there any way to add static emails to an existing list? or it must be a created recipients first?
as mentionned here https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-a-Single-Recipient-to-a-List-POST